# Search for a char value in a binary seach tree C

Tags: c, char, binary-search-tree

i have a binary search tree with an INT key(int cod). There are the structs used for it, working well at testing; A binary tree node has its information from a Task struct

```
struct Task {
    int cod;
    char*inginer;
    int nrActivitati;
    char**activitati;
};

struct nod {
    Task info;
    nod *st, *dr;
};

struct nodLista {
    Task info;
    nodLista *next;
};
```

I want to search this binary tree for a char value(char ing[20]). If one or more nodes contain a Task object which stores exactly the same value in **inginer** field, i want the variable **nrTasks** to add to its current value the **nrActivitati** field value from that object...But something is not working here. Any ideas? Hope you understand my explanation. This function returns only 0, no matter the node information.

```
int nrTaskuri(nod*root, char ing[20]) {
    int nrTasks = 0;
    if (root) {
        if (strcmp(root->info.inginer, ing)==0) {
            nrTasks += root->info.nrActivitati;
        }
        if (root->st) {
            nrTaskuri(root->st, ing);
        }
        if (root->dr) {
            nrTaskuri(root->dr, ing);
        }
    }
    else printf("Tree is empty");

    return nrTasks;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you're ignoring the return values from the recursive calls to `nrTaskuri`.

Try this:

```
    if (root->st) {
        nrTasks += nrTaskuri(root->st, ing);
    }
    if (root->dr) {
        nrTasks += nrTaskuri(root->dr, ing);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Something so simple, I didn't even notice. Now works fine